# How to load CSV data into SPSS using syntax (not drop downs)

Tags: csv, spss

I want to load in some CSV data into SPSS. But I want to have the syntax so that I don't have to go through the ignominy of using drop down menus.

Normally there is a tool to copy some syntax when you go through the drop downs, but I can't find it.

All I see is this and none of that works.

[image: Drop downs leads to this, no syntax generator]

Can someone either show me how to generate the syntax from this menu, or give me some example syntax for loading in CSV files into SPSS?

I've tried the advanced text wizard which has this option...

[image]

...but it doesn't work. I press finish after asking it to paste the syntax and nothing appears. ARGH!

Comment: Your first screen shot has a "paste" button on it - when I click that I get a new window with a few additional selections and again a "paste" button. When I click THAT I get the syntax pasted at the end of whichever syntax window is open and selected (or in a new one if none was open).

Comment: I must have a faulty SPSS because the final paste is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say why the PASTE won't work for you, here's some basic syntax (I pasted from my window menus) you can use to import your data -

```
GET DATA  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE="yourpath\yourfile.csv"
  /ENCODING='UTF8'
  /DELIMITERS=","
  /QUALIFIER='"'
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=2
  /DATATYPEMIN PERCENTAGE=95.0
  /VARIABLES=
  var1 AUTO
  var2 AUTO
  var3 AUTO
  var4 AUTO
  /MAP.
RESTORE.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME mydata WINDOW=FRONT.
```

Answer (score 0):

So, my advice for anyone trying to do this, and I do still hope for a better answer, is to change the csv to xlsx, and load it in that way.

You will need something like this:

```
   GET DATA
  /TYPE=XLSX
  /FILE='Path_to_your_data\my_data.xlsx'
  /SHEET=name 'sheet_name'
  /CELLRANGE=FULL
  /READNAMES=ON
  /DATATYPEMIN PERCENTAGE=95.0
  /HIDDEN IGNORE=YES.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME DataSet5 WINDOW=FRONT.
```

SPSS sucks!